# Do we need an interface router per each subnetwork?

Tags: networking, routes, ip, subnet

I have the knowledge to do `subneting`math, but I confused what device that is used to separate each subnet from other ones? who will route packets to the right subnetwork destination? If it is the router, do we need an interface per each subnetwork?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is the router the one in charge of routing the packets to the right subnetworks. You need to assign each subnetwork to a different interface, but this does not necessarily mean physical interfaces. You can use virtual interfaces as well.

Here's a Cisco link about them:

> http://www.cisco.com/en/US/docs/ios/12_4/interface/configuration/guide/inb_virt.html

Answer (score 0):

If you have multiple internal subnets, the industry standard is to create sub-interfaces and encapsulate as a DOT1Q trunk between the router and the switch.

Example R1

Interfaces:

S0/0/0 - used for WAN
Fa0/1 -physical internal interface
Fa0/1.100 Data VLAN (sub-interface)
Fa0/1.200 Voice VLAN (sub-interface)

Switch. Will have VLANs 100 and 200 on it and the trunk port will be configured as encapsulation DOT1Q. With these commands.
"switchport mode trunk"
"switchport trunk encapsulation dot1q"

I have literally done this thousands of times. Don't waste money on separate router interfaces for internal subnets.

Hope this helps.